# Cannot convert to timestamp

Tags: c#, datetime, timestamp, sybase

I try to insert a new row into the Lexware Database (Sybase SQL Anywhere).
Now I need to insert a timestamp and I don't know how. It always says cannot convert to timestamp. The date I need is 30.12.1899 00:00:00. I'm working in C# my code looks like this:

```
command = new OdbcCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO LX_PLAUSIS (dateAbrech) VALUES ('{0}')", new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 00, 00, 00), connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I know DateTime is not a timestamp so it has to be like this

```
command = new OdbcCommand(String.Format("INSERT INTO LX_PLAUSIS (dateAbrech) VALUES ('{0}')", *Here has to be the timestamp*, connection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: _AFAIK_ sybase `timestamp` is not related any date and time part. How about choosing a different column type? Like `DATETIME`.

Comment: I know but if I select dateAbrech it gives me a datetime and if I just don't insert it it says that I have to insert it. Sorry for my english

Comment: Anyway if you wann use onlu string value it should be like:
'20151223 23:00:00.000'

Comment: You could try to format your `DateTime` object as a string in ISO 8601 format: `new DateTime(1899,12,30,0,0,0).ToString("s")`.

Answer (score 0):

> ### lzydrmr :
>
> > "You could try to format your DateTime object as a string in ISO 8601 format: new DateTime(1899,12,30,0,0,0).ToString("s")"

Thanks it worked :)